# Can Sonatype Nexus publish indexes after a commit?

Tags: maven-2, ide, indexing, nexus, sonatype

We have a Nexus repository, that holds our software (surprise ...). In our IDEs, we added the repositories, so we can navigate them in a visual manner.

Problem: the IDE uses the .index folder (with it's gz file), which is currently updated every night.

What I want is: if anyone adds an artifact, the .index should be updated automatically. Is that possible?

What I don't want is: make the index update itself every so many minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Exporting the index into the consumable binary and chunking out the indexes isn't a trivial process so it's not something we've setup to allow publishing every time a release or snapshot is published. It's also a waste because it's unlikely that consumers of the index are updating every n seconds.

The internal indexes are however updated in realtime and searches against the Nexus UI will have the latest and greatest. We are working on more tightly integrating the IDE and Nexus internal indexes to eliminate the publish/consume loop.